# Gre algebra question, percentage

Tags: algebra-precalculus

During a certain month, $20$ percent of all the electricity used by a household was used by the water heater. The cost per kilowatt-hour of the electricity used by the water heater was half the cost per kilowatt-hour of the rest of the electricity used. For that month, the cost of the electricity used by the water heater was what fraction of the cost of the electricity used by the household?

I don't think I understand the question but I will share my approach here.

If we have $20\%$ of electricity used was water heater, then $80\%$ is what the rest of the electricity, and water heater costs is half of the rest costs. Let $E$ denotes electricity usage and $C$ is the total costs.

Maybe we have,

$$ 20\%E = \frac{1}{2}C$$
$$ 80\%E = C$$

But it doesn't seem make sense to me even I wrote it, haven't solve this kind of algebra for long time, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can pretend the household used 100 kilowatt-hours, and that the water heater cost is \$1/kwh and that the other cost is \$2/kwh.

- Water heater used 20 kilowatt-hours; each kilowatt-hour costs \$1; total cost from water heater is \$20.
- Rest of the household used 80 kilowatt-hours; each of these kilowatt-hours costs \$2; total cost from rest of household is \$160.